# Getting bad request 400 from react front end when forget-passoword asp.net api

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, tailwind-css

I have tried tried doing changes on the backend to gain . The backend works well when tested with swagger and even sends a reset password on email. When it comes to front end where am using react tailwind it gives a bad request 400 error:
Request URL:
https://localhost:7079/api/Account/forgot-password
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
400 Bad Request
Remote Address:
[::1]:7079
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

I have tried changing the react code from using fetch to axios post to no gain.
Here is my frontend:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
//import input from '@material-ui/core/input';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const title = 'Forgot Password Screen';

function ForgotPassword() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
  const [messageFromServer, setMessageFromServer] = useState('');
  const [showNullError, setShowNullError] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  const sendEmail = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (email === '') {
      setShowError(false);
      setMessageFromServer('');
      setShowNullError(true);
    } else {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://localhost:7079/api/Account/forgot-password', {
          email,
        });
        if (response.data === 'recovery email sent') {
          setShowError(false);
          setMessageFromServer('recovery email sent');
          setShowNullError(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.response.data);
        if (error.response.data === 'email not in db') {
          setShowError(true);
          setMessageFromServer('');
          setShowNullError(false);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="py-10 flex flex-col items-center">
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">{title}</h2>
      <form className="profile-form" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
        <input
          style={{ width: '100%' }}
          id="email"
          label="Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Email Address"
        />
        <button className="btn btn-primary mt-4 w-full">
          Send Password Reset Email
        </button>
      </form>
      {showNullError && (
        <p className="text-red-600 mt-4">The email address cannot be null.</p>
      )}
      {showError && (
        <div className="mt-4">
          <p>
            That email address isn't recognized. Please try again or register
            for a new account.
          </p>
          <Link to="/register" className="inline-block mt-2 text-primary underline cursor-pointer">
            Register
          </Link>
        </div>
      )}
      {messageFromServer === 'recovery email sent' && (
        <div className="mt-4">
          <h3>Password Reset Email Successfully Sent!</h3>
        </div>
      )}
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary mt-4 w-full">
        Go Home
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ForgotPassword;
```

Comment: Can you show youre cors policy code? have you added https://localhost:7079 to the allowed origins?

Comment: actually i was a able to pass this but still facing other issue. I did changes on the backend to redirect the url to the frontend reset password form that is after verification of the token. The issue am facing now is that when a user clicks the link on email, it redirects him to the frontend and tries to open the reset password component but fails to open it . The link instead loads the reset form then immediately redirects to login page so user is not able to put new credentials

Comment: Happy you got the solution for your problem. but this new issue sounds like you have a new unrelated problem to your question. so open a new question and provider the relevant code snippets